# Problem with glOrtho: the curve disappears from the scene

Tags: opengl, curve, orthographic, glu

I have curve, a parable (y=x*x) for x in [0, 10]. I have used:

```
glOrtho(-10 - 3, 10 + 3, -(y(10)+ 3) * (GLfloat) h / (GLfloat) w,
                        (y(10) + 3) * (GLfloat) h / (GLfloat) w, -1, 1);
```

a part on top is clipped.
Moreover if I consider a parable in [8, 10] and I set:

```
glOrtho(-10 - 3, 10 + 3, -(y(10)+ 3) * (GLfloat) h / (GLfloat) w,
                        (y(10) + 3) * (GLfloat) h / (GLfloat) w, -1, 1);
```

my curve disappears from the scene. How can I modify the commands to visualize the curve?

Comment: @ httpdigest Clearly y(10)=10^2, I am talking about a parable. So in opengl I am referring to evaluate the function at the point 10. A parable in [0, 10] means that I draw with a polyline the curve with a set of point with x-coordinate from 0 to 10.

Comment: Can you please show a picture?

Comment: My window is even completely without the curve in case of an intterval of type [-10, -8]...